# Next js share state between client component without making the root a client component as well

Tags: next.js13

I have a big static page that I want to keep as a client component, in this page I have 3 buttons (added as client components) that have to open the same modal, my original idea was to create a modal as a client component and put it in the static page but I don't know how to pass the data from the buttons without leveling up the useState and make the entire page a client component. An alternative way that is functional but not too fancy would be to import the modal component inside every button and have there 3 instances of them so I can pass the props and keep the state in the button.

Do you have any other idea how to have a single modal component without making the entire page a client component?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.